cargo.toml many versions error? (master + v2.0)
I am new to Solana and Rust, I took latest from https://github.com/solana-labs/solana.git
I open cargo.toml (I tried "master" and "v2.0" branch) from VSCode, many versions errors.
Is that to be expected?

I tried cargo update (Yes aware you should build with ./scripts/cargo-install-all.sh ... just trying), but error: "perhaps a crate was updated and forgotten to be re-vendored?":
D:\..\solana>cargo clean
     Removed 4210 files, 845.9MiB total

D:\dev\SOL\solana>cargo update
    Updating git repository `https://github.com/RustCrypto/AEADs`
    Updating git repository `https://github.com/solana-labs/crossbeam`
    Updating git repository `https://github.com/solana-labs/curve25519-dalek.git`
    Updating git repository `https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-tokio.git`
    Updating crates.io index
error: failed to select a version for the requirement `spl-token-group-interface = "=0.1.1"`
candidate versions found which didn't match: 0.4.2, 0.3.0, 0.2.5, ...
location searched: crates.io index
required by package `solana-account-decoder v2.0.0 (D:\dev\SOL\solana\account-decoder)`
perhaps a crate was updated and forgotten to be re-vendored?

    D:\..\solana>cargo update
        ...
        Updating git repository `https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-tokio.git`
        Updating crates.io index
    error: failed to select a version for the requirement `spl-token-group-interface = "=0.1.1"`
    candidate versions found which didn't match: 0.4.2, 0.3.0, 0.2.5, ...
    location searched: crates.io index
    required by package `solana-account-decoder v2.0.0 (D:\..\solana\account-decoder)`
    perhaps a crate was updated and forgotten to be re-vendored?

Finally cargo build:
D:\..\solana>cargo build
   Compiling unicode-ident v1.0.2
   Compiling cfg-if v1.0.0
   Compiling lazy_static v1.4.0
   Compiling winapi v0.3.9
...
   Compiling rand_core v0.6.4
error: expected item, found `..`
 --> C:\Users\norman\.cargo\git\checkouts\crossbeam-2841e3eed153c98b\fd279d7\crossbeam-epoch\no_atomic.rs:1:1
  |
1 | ../no_atomic.rs
  | ^^

   Compiling equivalent v1.0.0
   Compiling cpufeatures v0.2.7
error[E0425]: cannot find value `NO_ATOMIC_CAS` in this scope
  --> C:\Users\norman\.cargo\git\checkouts\crossbeam-2841e3eed153c98b\fd279d7\crossbeam-epoch\build.rs:27:8
   |
27 |     if NO_ATOMIC_CAS.contains(&&*target) {
   |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

   Compiling ryu v1.0.5
For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0425`.
error: could not compile `crossbeam-epoch` (build script) due to 2 previous errors
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...

Thanks

Hello, I am curious about the objective of trying to build the Solana monorepo.

The specific error you're seeing here is due to symlinks in the repo not being supported on Windows. You'll need to run the following steps:
    git config core.symlinks true
    find . -type l -delete
    git reset --hard

Building in Windows is very tricky unfortunately. There was just an update done with https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/pull/3118 -- you'll need to follow the steps to install the protobuf compiler and openssl, along with configuring a few environment variables.
After that, you can run cargo build for whatever component you need, such as the validator, sdk, etc. But even if you're familiar with the system, it still takes awhile.
